# Are the database-related objects such as connection object, command object, datareader, dataadapter,... unmanaged resources?

Tags: unmanagedresources

Are the database-related objects such as connection object, command object, datareader, dataadapter,... unmanaged resources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The objects you refer to are part of the .NET framework, and are garbage-collectable.  So in that sense they are managed resources.

A better question would be, do these objects implement `IDisposable`?  If they do, you can use the `using` keyword in C# to clean them up once they go out of scope, or call their `dispose()` method manually.

An example of using the `using` keyword with `SqlConnection` and `SqlDataAdapter` objects is here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jasonsalas/archive/2005/02/08/368811.aspx